# spidev to read eeprom id

Tags: linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, spi, device-tree

OS: Linux
I'm writing a spidev application in userspace to read EEPROM id. I have my device tree entry as following:

```
spi0: spi@ffda4000 {
    compatible = "snps,dw-apb-ssi";
    #address-cells = <1>;
    #size-cells = <0>;
    reg = <0xffda4000 0x100>;
    interrupt-parent = <&intc>;
    interrupts = <GIC_SPI 101 IRQ_TYPE_LEVEL_HIGH>;
    num-cs = <2>;
    cs-gpios = <&porta 7 GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH>, <&porta 0 GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH>;
    bus-num = <0>;
    tx-dma-channel = <&pdma 16>;
    rx-dma-channel = <&pdma 17>;
    clocks = <&spi_m_clk>;
    status = "disabled";
};
```

and then:

```
&spi0 {
    status = "okay";
    m25p10_spi@0 {
        compatible = "m25p10";
        reg = <0>;  /* chip select */
        spi-max-frequency = <20000000>;
        /* m25p,fast-read; */
        enable-dma = <0>;
    };
    spidev@0 {
        compatible = "rohm,dh2228fv";
        reg = <0>;  /* chip select */
        spi-max-frequency = <20000000>;
        enable-dma = <0>;
    };
};
```

Idea is to have spidev at same node as m25p10 so that when user space application open handle to "/dev/spidev0.0", it is actually talking to m25p10. But I can't get linux boot up. Is there anything wrong with this approach?

Comment: I get it to bootup. The error code it says is:
dw_spi_mmio ffda4000.spi: chipselect 0 already in use

How can i make spidev talk to m25p10 chip then?

Comment: *"How can i make spidev talk to m25p10 chip then?"* -- Remove one of the duplicate nodes, i.e. the m25p10_spi@0 node.

Comment: @sawdust I'm coming over to Linux world from WinCE, so may be I don't understand this idea of spidev! So I can use either m25p10 driver or spidev in my code? 
If I remove m25p10_spi@0, I break existing code being used by other kernel utilities. I wanted to get spidev in so that userspace applications could talk to m25p10 device.
It seems that is an invalid scenario, is that true?

Comment: right way to use devicetree is differant address. use spidev@<addr>

Comment: @Devidas Wait, so spidev@1 can talk to m25p10@0? remember, the only reason I want spidev is to be able to talk to m25p10!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not work. One device - one definition in DT.

Also, why do you need to have `spidev` device? You already have `m25p10_spi`, which should show up as MTD device (something like `/dev/mtd0`), and there should be no problems accessing it from user space.

UPDATE:

It looks like OP wants to keep MTD and read device unique ID via RDID command, which is not supported by current m25p10 driver.

I might be wrong, but for me the easiest solution would be to extend the driver to create `sysfs` entry with RDID data, that is read during probing.

Some valuable resources:

- [LDD3](https://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3)
- [Linux kernel documentation](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/Documentation)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, I can open "/dev/mtd0" but I can't read device ID using mtd interface. I want to let user space application read and verify eeprom id (RDID). 
Now i understand; i can either use m25p10 or spidev. Since I can't remove m25p10; I would have to find a way to let usersapce application read spi register (RDID). Any ideas on that?

Comment: After a quick look to the latest m25p10 driver it looks like this is not supported. You might want to extend the driver to, for example, create sysfs entry on successful probe. I see that RDID is read during that stage, so you can just store it for sysfs readout.

Comment: I was inclining towards same direction but wanted not to do it :-)
I'm newbie to linux device drivers (embedded) coming over from WinCE. Would you recommend some good books/material to become expert in linux device drivers? Please.